# How to input the dictionary structure in 'values' argument using the aws_ssm_parameter in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have one parameter in AWS System Manager, type of the value is string, but value has a dictionary structure:

Value:

{"key1": "value1","key2": "value2","key3": "value3"}

Now i'm trying to create this parameter using the cloudformation. But i received an error, when trying to write this in cloudformation:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Systems Manager Parameter Store Parameters
Resources:
  Test-Channels:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      Name: test-Channels
      Description:Lambda required parameter key and values
      Type: String
      Value: "{ "key1": "value1","key2": "value2", "key3", "value3"}"
```

error from cloudformation:
Property validation failure: [Value of property {/Value} does not match type {String}]

could someone please advise what I did wrong or the proper way of assigning dictionary type of value to parameter name using cloudformation?

Thank a lot!

Comment: What is the actual template?

Comment: AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09" 
Description: Systems Manager Parameter Store Parameters 
Resources: Test-Channels: 
 Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter 
 Properties: 
  Name: test-Channels 
  Description:Lambda required parameter key and values 
  Type: String 
  Value: "{ "key1": "value1","key2": "value2", "key3", "value3"}"

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Systems Manager Parameter Store Parameters
Resources:
    TestChannels:
        Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
        DeletionPolicy: Delete
        Properties:
            Name: test-Channels
            Description: Lambda required parameter key and values
            Type: String
            Value: dddd
            Value: '{ "key1": "value1","key2": "value2", "key3", "value3"}'
```

Comment: @jiachang Really? I though its still unclear what you can do as you haven't accepted the answer as correct.